# Property type casting in Swift: good practice

Tags: ios, swift

Lately I've been wondering if there's any difference between the following two ways of typecasting a property in Swift? I know there's no difference in the property being made, but I was wondering about compiler performance or just good practices.

```
let x: CGFloat = 5
```

vs

```
let y = 5 as CGFloat
```

Thanks!

Comment: I personally prefer: let y = CGFloat(5)

Comment: Only the last one is typecasting. The first one is simply declaring the type of a constant. Either way works and it's mostly a matter of opinion which is better. It's much more usual to see the first. There's also `let z = CGFloat(5)` which is more common than your last one.

Comment: The first one is better because, as @KennethBruno said, it's just declaring the type. The compiler may be smart enough to produce the same compiled code with the second one, but if not then it might be slightly slower, so first is better all around. And as for using the `CGFloat` constructor being passed a 5 as Kenneth mentions, there's no reason we should need to explicitly call the CGFloat constructor, and that one I would say is most likely to be slower if the compiler doesn't also optimize that one away.

Comment: @Gavin I'm pretty sure each one will be optimized away with most reasonable optimization settings. One or the other may slow the compiler down a tiny bit but use whichever one is more clear for you. Certainly `let x: CGFloat = 5` is the most straightforward.

Comment: @KennethBruno Agreed, that one is the best answer.

Comment: @dfri But that example is contrived. You're using a string literal, so you could just use an integer literal instead. Obviously in situations where the exact value is not known at compile time, you might need to use a specific method to covert it. But you would never write `let x: Int? = Int("1")` in reality, because it's just pointless when `let x = 1` is much simpler.

Answer (score 3):

The `as` operator is used for typecasting.  Therefore for the second case you are saying y is equal to an integer 5, typecast into a `CGFloat`.  Given the two choices, the first one is more explicit and preferred.

The first choice is not a typecast as you imply in the question.  The `CGFloat` has a `init` function that takes an `Int`. Therefore again it is preferred from a compiler perspective.

Comment: Just to add the `as` operator can be equipped with `?` or '!'. `as!` denotes a definite `known` type cast and `as?` denotes a nullable "could be" e.g. if you `let a = b as? Type` either you get a result or nil

Comment: per @Adrian, in the example `y` would be implied as type `CGFloat?`

Comment: `as` without a `?` or `!` casts using inference.. I've added to my answer to explain inference...

Comment: Does that explain it? I couldn't think of a better way to lay it out :)

Comment: This discussion is veering away from the original question. `as` does not "casts using inference". If the reference is not a subclass or if the new type does not have a convenience initializer using the old type, then the cast fails.  `let y = 5 as CGFloat` does NOT make `y` of type `CGFloat?`.

Comment: 5 (or any whole number) can be seen as a float or double (or CGFloat) The same goes with a `.0` value (without a concrete type) e.g. `let y = 5 as CGFloat` and `let x = 5.0 as Int`now try `let z = y as Float` yet `let z = 5 as Float` works. This is because the inferred types are being used. And about your original question, thats another thing I'll post on xD

Comment: Both examples you used are "good practice". Ideally speaking, though tedious, strictly typing variables (vars and lets) is ideal. On top of that, you only need to type-cast if you get a 'rogue value' from somewhere, i.e. a function that returns an AnyObject value or a non "CGFloat" value. Keeping your variables tightly typed at declaration removes a lot of the need for type-casting later on. If you find yourself casting a lot, then there's a question as to why data is changing form and, as to whether the original declaration was correct in the first place

Answer (score 0):

This is (almost) entirely a style question.

I think (as offered by @Kenneth),

```
let w = CGFloat(5)
```

is "more swifty" (currently, c. Apr 2016), but style will obviously continue to morph as Swift becomes more mature,

this is the format you'd want for an inline example, for example

```
CGPathAddArc(path, nil, p1.x, p1.y, slice.radius, 0, CGFloat(M_PI_4), true)
```

I would also offer, if you don't specifically want/need a `CGFloat` but really just a floating point number, the suggested initialization would be

```
let z = 5.0
```

which would imply `Double` as the type,

and to reiterate that `as` is intended as run-time type checking and conversion, possibly resulting in a `nil` value (that said, anything the compiler can safely execute/simplify, it will)

```
let y = 5 as CGFloat
```

this could lead to some reader confusion, since the usual intent is runtime casting.

Comment: `let y = 5 as CGFloat` would not result in an implied type of `CGFloat?`.  The `as` operator (rather than `as?` or `as!`) means that it's a cast that the compiler can guarantee.  So it isn't a runtime operation or conversion and would never be nil at runtime.

Comment: thanks for the correction, @daniel - updated above